# Update a numeric property of a JSON object in an array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My JSON **config.json**:

```
[  
   {  
      "names":"Steam",
      "count": 1,
   },
   {  
      "names":"game",
      "count": 2,
   }
]
```

I need to update `count`'s property in the array in c#.
I tried

```
JObject objectproperty = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"config.json"));
```

but this gives me the error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."
```

Comment: That's not a valid json object

Comment: The exception message tells you the solution. Use `JArray` for arrays, not `JObject` (which is, obviously, for objects)

Comment: I misstiped Mardoxx. Anyways this wasn't my problem in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [JToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) 
Assuming that your JSON is:
(notice I had to remove some `,`)

```
[  
   {  
      "names":"Steam",
      "count": 1
   },
   {  
      "names":"game",
      "count": 2
   }
]
```

You can use this:

```
var config_file = @"config.json";

var objectproperty = JToken.Parse(File.ReadAllText(config_file));
foreach (var obj in objectproperty)
{
    var count = (long)obj["count"];

    obj["count"] = count * 3;
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(config_file, objectproperty.ToString());
```